# Python - Removing duplicates in list only by using filter and lambda

Tags: python

I need to remove duplicates in a list without set, functions or loops - only by using filter and a lambda function.

My attempt was:

```
list(filter(lambda x: x in l[:].remove(x), l))
```

But remove returns the removed item and not the whole list. Any suggestions?

Comment: But why not sets, functions and loops? You didn't tell that.

Comment: That's the assignment. It's a part of an algorithm I need to build for homework.

Comment: Can you give an example?  Should `[1, 2, 2, 3]` be turned into `[1, 2, 3]` or are you looking to filter out the entry all together and end up with `[1, 3]` instead?

Comment: For the input [1, 2, 2, 3] we will get [1, 2, 3].

Comment: I think your check is wrong.  `filter()` needs the function to return `True` for the things to keep.  So you want `x not in` rather than `x in`.

Comment: ...though I don't think it's quite what you want either.  I believe it's only going to keep the entries that have no duplicates rather than keeping one of the duplicates in the final list.  If you were able to use reduce, you could do something more interesting.

Comment: ...or enumerate

Comment: Can you use a new list?

Comment: How will the new list be used to remove duplicates?

Comment: If you could use reduce, that would help too.

Answer (score 2):

You need to keep some state somehow.  If you can use a new list, you could do something like this:

```
g = l[:]
filter(lambda x: g.remove(x) is None and g.count(x) == 0, l)
```

The above removes duplicates differently.  If you had `l = [1, 2, 2, 3, 2]`, you'd end up with `[1, 3, 2]` as the resultant list.

Or create an empty list and use it to keep track of what you've seen:

```
seen = []
return filter(lambda x: seen.append(x) is None if x not in seen else False, l)
```

Both the above is pretty akin to using sets, though far less efficient. :-)  And both are using a goofy mechanism to allow mutate a list in place but return a True/False result (the `is None` portion in both of them is allowing us to chain expressions together).

If you can use `map` and `enumerate`, you could do something like:

```
map(lambda t: t[1],
    filter(lambda t: l[:t[0]].count(t[1]) == 0, enumerate(l)))
```

(it uses the current index to look into the previous part of the list to find duplicates)

If you can use list comprehensions, you could remove the use of `map`:

```
[x for i, x in filter(lambda t: l[:t[0]].count(t[1]) == 0,
                      enumerate(l))]
```

If you could use `reduce`, then you could do something like:

```
reduce(lambda r, x: r + [x] if x not in r else r, l, [])
```

as you can keep state by passing the result from one iteration to the next.

But somehow you're going to need to have a record of what has been seen.  None of this is what I'd call elegant Python code though, except maybe the `reduce` version--though it's not performant.

Answer (score 0):

I made a solution using only a `lambda` function.

The following `lambda` function returns a list corresponding to the list passed as argument, without duplicates:

```
lambda l: (lambda u, a: u(u, a)) ((lambda f, x: x if len(x) <= 1 else (f(f, x[1:]) if x[0] in x[1:] else ([x[0]] + f(f, x[1:])))), l)
```

Since the target is a bit different, I posted a separate Q/A, where I explain this: [Removing duplicates using only lambda functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41524133/removing-duplicates-using-only-lambda-functions/41524134#41524134).