# Removing duplicates using only lambda functions

Tags: python, lambda

I came across the question [Python - Removing duplicates in list only by using filter and lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41522601/python-removing-duplicates-in-list-only-by-using-filter-and-lambda), where the OP asks how to remove duplicate elements from a Python list using exclusively `filter` and `lambda` functions.

This made me wonder, is it possible, from a theoretical point of view, to remove the duplicates from a Python list using only `lambda` functions?

If so, how can we do that?

In this case, "removinge the duplicates" means "keeping exactly one occurrence of each element present in the original list", so `[1,2,1,3,1,4]` should become `[1,2,3,4]`.

In addition, the goal is to write only one `lambda`, so the code would be a one-liner like:

```
lambda l: """do something that returns l without duplicates"""
```

No external variable must be used.

Besides, as for the above question, nothing "fancy" is allowed, especially the `set` function, as well as `reduce`, `map`...

Basically, no other function, even the built-in, should be called.

Comment: lambda functions only and no temporary placeholders/containers?

Comment: @wwii Edited my question; yes, the code must exclusively consist in one lambda function, so no additional container is allowed.

Comment: Sometimes it is a bit tricky but generally you can find a way to write a *lambda* version of a function regardless of how messy or unreadable it may be.

Comment: @wwii Check my answer to see how messy it is :)

Comment: ```lambda a: list(set(a))```??

Comment: @wwii I edited my question once more, but please check the question I linked: no built-in except `filter` is allowed, so I am expecting that no built-in at all is called.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From a theoritecal point of view, if a computational problem requires an input and an output without side-effect, lambda calculus can probably solve it (more generally, lambda calculus is Turing complete, cf [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus)).

Now for the implementation, the following `lambda` function takes a list argument, and returns a list where all the duplicates have been removed:

```
lambda l: (lambda u, a: u(u, a)) ((lambda f, x: x if len(x) <= 0 else (f(f, x[1:]) if x[0] in x[1:] else ([x[0]] + f(f, x[1:])))), l)
```

Here is an unwrapped version:

```
lambda l:
    (lambda u, a: u(u, a))
    (
        (lambda f, x: x if len(x) <= 0
                        else
                        (
                            f(f, x[1:]) if x[0] in x[1:]
                                        else ([x[0]] + f(f, x[1:]))
                        )
         ),
         l
    )
```

The function consists in a `lambda` version of the following recursive function:

```
def f(l):
    if len(l) <= 0:
        return l
    elif l[0] in l[1:]:
        return f(l[1:])
    else:
        return ([l[0]] + f(l[1:]))
```

To emulate a recursive call, the equivalent `lambda` takes an additional function as argument, that will be itself:

```
lambda f, x: x if len(x) <= 0
               else
               (
                   f(f, x[1:]) if x[0] in x[1:]
                               else ([x[0]] + f(f, x[1:]))
               )
```

Then, another `lambda` calls this previous function, passing itself as argument (besides the list):

```
lambda u, a: u(u, a)
```

Finally, an outer `lambda` wraps everything up, that takes only a list as argument.

Comment: Neat. For some reason [Greenspun's tenth rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greenspun%27s_tenth_rule) comes to mind ;-)

Comment: @snakecharmerb Indeed, except that in this case, C/Fortran is Python, and Common Lisp is Python :)