# one-liner reduce in Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.x, reduce

In Python3, I am looking for a way to compute in **one line** a `lambda` function called on elements two by two. Let’s say I want to compute the [LCM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_common_multiple) of a list of integers, this can be done in [one line in Python2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15995/useful-code-which-uses-reduce-in-python#282206):

```
print reduce(lambda a,b: a * b // gcd(a, b), mylist)
```

Is it possible to do the same in one line Python3 (implied, without `functools.reduce`)?

In Python3 I know that `filter`, `map` and `reduce` are gone. I don’t feel I need `filter` and `map` anymore because they can be written in Python3 in a shorter and more clear fashion but I thought I could find a nice replacement for `reduce` as well, except I haven’t found any. I [have](https://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#builtins) seen [many](http://www.diveintopython3.net/porting-code-to-python-3-with-2to3.html#reduce) articles [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13638898/how-to-use-filter-map-and-reduce-in-python-3#13638960) suggest [to](http://www.bogotobogo.com/python/python_fncs_map_filter_reduce.php#filterreduce) use [`functools.reduce`](https://docs.python.org/3.0/library/functools.html#functools.reduce) or to “[write out the accumulation loop explicitly](http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=98196)” but I’d like to do it without importing functools and in one line.

If it makes it any easier, I should mention I use functions that are both [associative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_property) and [commutative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutative_property). For instance with a function `f` on the list `[1,2,3,4]`, the result will be good if it either computes:

- `f(1,f(2,f(3,4)))`
- `f(f(1,2),f(3,4))`
- `f(f(3,f(1,4)),2)`
- or any other order

Comment: Why do you want to do it in one line? And given that, why don't you want to use `functools.reduce`? Both these requirements seem arbitrary and not of practical use

Comment: To add to Chris's comment, `reduce` was moved from the global namespace to `functools` precisely *because* it was mostly useful for terse (some might say, obscure) one-liners.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41524133/removing-duplicates-using-only-lambda-functions/41524134#41524134

Comment: @Chris_Rands I’d like to do it in one line so that I can use the result directly (e.g. as an argument to a function). Putting `reduce` in `functools` feels like they didn’t design a proper replacement for it (unlike `filter`and `map` which got awesome replacements) so I was looking for one, if any. Plus sometimes I work in an environment where `import` is not recommended or even prohibited.

Comment: Your reasoning for not using `functools.reduce` doesn't make much sense to me...

Comment: `filter` and `map` are still in Python 3, though comprehensions are preferred.  `reduce` is in `functools` as mentioned.  See the BDFL's post here http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=98196

Answer (score 2):

So I actually did come up with something. I do not guarantee the performance though, but it is a one-liner using exclusively `lambda` functions - nothing from `functools` or `itertools`, not even a single loop.

```
my_reduce = lambda l, f: (lambda u, a: u(u, a))((lambda v, m: None if len(m) == 0 else (m[0] if len(m) == 1 else v(v, [f(m[0], m[1])] + m[2:]))), l)
```

This is somewhat unreadable, so here it is expanded:

```
my_reduce = lambda l, f: (
    lambda u, a: u(u, a)) (
        (lambda v, m: None if len(m) == 0
                           else (m[0] if len(m) == 1
                                      else v(v, [f(m[0], m[1])] + m[2:])
                                )
        ),
        l
    )
```

Test:

```
>>> f = lambda a,b: a+b
>>> my_reduce([1, 2, 3, 4], f)
10
>>> my_reduce(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], f)
'abcd'
```

Please check [this other post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41524134/7051394) for a deeper explanation of how this works.

The principle if to emulate a recursive function, by using a `lambda` function whose first parameter is a function, and will be itself.

This recursive function is embedded inside of a function that effectively triggers the recursive calling: `lambda u, a: u(u, a)`.

Finally, everything is wrapped in a function whose parameters are a list and a binary function.

---

Using `my_reduce` with your code:

```
my_reduce(mylist, lambda a,b: a * b // gcd(a, b))
```

Comment: I was wondering how long it would take someone to bust out the Y combinator.

Comment: @Sneftel I don't understand o_o

Comment: I guess @Sneftel is referring to [Y combinator, one of the fixed-point combinators in untyped lambda calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_combinator#Fixed_point_combinators_in_lambda_calculus). (Not to be confused with the [similarly named company](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Y_Combinator_(company)). ([disambiguation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Y_combinator)))

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a sequence that is at least one item long you can simply define `reduce` recursivly like this:

```
def reduce(func, seq): return seq[0] if len(seq) == 1 else func(reduce(func, seq[:-1]), seq[-1])
```

The long version would be slightly more readable:

```
def reduce(func, seq):
    if len(seq) == 1:
        return seq[0]
    else:
        return func(reduce(func, seq[:-1]), seq[-1])
```

However that's recursive and python isn't very good at recursive calls (meaning slow and the recursion limit prevents prosessing sequences longer than 300 items). A much faster implementation would be:

```
def reduce(func, seq):
    tmp = seq[0]
    for item in seq[1:]:
        tmp = func(tmp, item)
    return tmp
```

But because of the loop it can't be put in one-line. It could be solved using side-effects:

```
def reduce(func, seq): d = {}; [d.__setitem__('last', func(d['last'], i)) if 'last' in d else d.__setitem__('last', i) for i in seq]; return d['last']
```

or:

```
def reduce(func, seq): d = {'last': seq[0]}; [d.__setitem__('last', func(d['last'], i)) for i in seq[1:]]; return d['last']
```

Which is the equivalent of:

```
def reduce(func, seq): 
    d = {} 
    for item in seq:
        if 'last' in d:
            d['last'] = func(d['last'], item)
        else:
            d['last'] = item
    return d['last']  # or "d.get('last', 0)"
```

That should be faster but it's not exactly pythonic because the list-comprehension in the one-line implementation is just used because of the side-effects.