# Functional way to replace reduce()

Tags: python, python-3.x

In Python 3, `reduce()` has been moved to [`functools.reduce()`](https://docs.python.org/3.0/library/functools.html#functools.reduce) and [apparently](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13638960/8080186) it's better to use list comprehensions or plain loops for better readability.

I want to print the XOR'ed value of all elements in a list.

```
# My implementation with functools
from functools import reduce
print(reduce(lambda a, b: a^b, [1, 3, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 2, 1]))
```

And I have this:

```
# My implementation without functools
def XOR(x):
    ans = 0
    for i in x:
        ans = ans ^ i
    return ans

print(XOR([1, 3, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 2, 1]))
```

**How can write a more functional version of this code without `reduce()`?**

(Please provide references or code in Python 3, if any.)

Comment: Just stick with `reduce()`. This is an excellent case for it, **there is no reason not to use it**.

Comment: Improvement: [`from operator import xor`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.xor), then use `reduce(xor, yourlist)`.

Comment: @AjitZero built-in `xor` is most likely written in C, which involves less Python runtime.

Comment: And, by the way, regarding "*reduce() has been moved to functools.reduce() and apparently it's better to use list comprehensions or plain loops for better readability*" – listcomps (and, more generally, generator expressions) can't replace `reduce` (the fold function), they target `map` and `filter`. `reduce` is a perfectly fine function, there is no reason for you to avoid it, if you don't adhere to Guido van Rossum's distaste for functional programming.

Comment: Not doing any self-promotion, but [here is a purely functional reduce](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44071474/7051394), that uses only `lambda`s. Not that it's extremely useful... But I found it pretty relevant.

Comment: @Rightleg I didn't mention performance considerations but there's lambda overhead to look out for (which I just learnt about). Thanks for the link!

Comment: @AjitZero Oh. if you're looking for performance, just don't use this. If you're looking for readibility, too. Actually, don't use it :)

Comment: @EliKorvigo I've been undecided on that since couldn't find an adequate replacement for `reduce()`; it seems like isn't such a big deal after all. Thanks!

Comment: Why do you need a replacement for `reduce`? it still exists.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I was under the impression that it's no longer a recommended practice to use `reduce()`; Oh well.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Although Guido van Rossum didn't much care for `reduce()`, enough of the community did want it, which is why it was moved to `functools` and not removed outright. It is performant, and *ideally* suited to your use case. **Just use it**.

You can make your case faster and more readable by using [`operator.xor()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.xor) to avoid the overhead of a new Python frame for a lambda:

```
from functools import reduce
from operator import xor

reduce(xor, [1, 3, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 2, 1])
```

Both `xor()` and `reduce()` are implemented in C. Calling back to the Python interpreter loop for the `lambda` is quite slow compared to calling another C function.

If you really must use a function, then use

```
def xor_reduce(values):
    result = 0
    for value in values:
        result ^= value
    return result
```

using in-place XOR, and better variable names.

Comment: How do you feel about using `itertools.accumulate` in these situations? like `for x in accumulate([1, 3, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 2, 1], lambda a, b: a^b): pass` then `print(x)`

Comment: @Chris_Rands: if the goal is to have the intermediate values, sure. But that is a different use case; `functools.reduce()` is going to be faster if all you wanted was the *final result*. And I still would use `operator.xor()`.