# how to create reduce() in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Currently, I am creating primitive equivalents of function like `map`, `filter`, `reduce` etc.

By primitive equivalents, I mean creating the equivalent of the above stated function, in shortest way possible, via language tools like loops, conditions etc.

To give insight of what i am trying to refer, I have already created primitive equivalents for `map` and `filter`.

**SYNTAX FOR MAP STATEMENT:-**

```
zip(function(), sequence)
```

**EQUIVALENT FOR `MAP`:-**

```
[function() for x in sequence]
```

**------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------**

**SYNTAX FOR FILTER STATEMENT:-**

```
filter(function(), sequence)
```

**EQUIVALENT FOR `FILTER`:-**

```
[x for x in sequence if (condition)]
```

***The difference between `map` and `filter` is that, `map` takes a generic function, on the other hand `filter` takes in a function that contains a condition, therefore, the output sequence size may be different then the input size in `filter`***

**----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------***

Now, I am not able to do the same for `reduce`. For those who are not familiar with `reduce()`-

> `reduce(function(), sequence)` function is used to apply a particular function passed in its argument to all of the sequence elements mentioned in the sequence passed along. `reduce()` has only a single return value, as opposed to a sequence returned by `map` and `filter`.

Example demonstrating working of `reduce()`:-

```
reduce(lambda x, y: x*y, [10, 20, 30])
```

Output of above statement:-

```
6000
```

**P.S.:-** I don't want lengthy functions/for loops, I want something equivalent to a one liner, like what i did when creating an equivalent for `map` and `filter`.

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44070877/one-liner-reduce-in-python3) is asking much the same thing, and the answers there indicate that it can't really be done—you can certainly write the reduce function in one line, but the canonical way to reduce a list is to import `functools.reduce`.

Comment: The very nature of reduce is why Guido removed it from Python 3.

Comment: https://repl.it/repls/CluelessUnkemptEvaluation