# Using the lambda function for a function that depends on the input

Tags: python, lambda

As an input, I have a list of nonnegative whole numbers which are supposed to be the coefficients of a polynomial. But I also want to evaluate the polynomial for a certain number x.

For example:

If we have `L=[2,3,1]` as an input and `x=42` we get `2x^2+3x+1=3655`
What I want is for example:

```
>>>p=polynomial([2,3,1])
>>>p(O)
1 
>>>p(42)
>>>3655
```

I guess I have to make use of the lambda function somehow, and I do know how it works for two variables on a given function, but in this case the function depends on my input.

```
def polynomial(coef):
coef=coef[::-1]
for i in range(len(coef)):
    p=lambda x: coef[i]*x**i
    p+=p
return lambda x: p
```

This is of course absolute nonsense, as I cannot add up one lambda function to another, but this is what my approaching "intuition" is.

Some hints are much appreciated.

Comment: You should use [`sympy`](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/intro.html)

Comment: "I guess I have to make use of the lambda function somehow" <- Why do you guess that? `lambda` functions can't do anything that regular named functions don't already do.

Comment: Is the usage of lambda mandatory? You could easily write a function returing a function (more precisely a closure) that does exactly what you want.

Comment: No it is not mandatory, I just recently learned what lambda functions are, so it just came up my mind..

Comment: BTW, is `coef[i]` supposed to be the coefficient of `x**i` or of `x**(degree - i)`? Your example suggests the latter, but the code suggests the former. (Maybe you meant `coef = coef[::-1]` rather than `coef = coef[::1]`?)

Comment: @MarkDickinson thanks, typo. coef[::-1][i] is the coefficient of x**i.

Comment: Related, if not duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/19837486/1639625

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple Python:

```
def make_poly(coefs):
    def poly(x):
        result = 0
        for c in coefs:
            result = result * x + c
        return result
    return poly

p = make_poly([2,3,1])

print(p(0))
print(p(42))
```

EDIT: code modified as suggested by Mark Dickinson in the comments

Comment: Don't hesitate to leave a comment before downvoting.

Comment: Thanks, but not exactly what I was looking for. What I was looking for is a function, where the input is a list before I am being asked to evaluate the polynomial at a point x, as I wrote above.

Btw, wasn't me downvoting.

Comment: @Tesla I think my code is doing just that. `make_poly` here is called `polynomial` in the example in your question. It takes a list as its input. It returns a function that evaulates the polynomial. It even gives the correct aswers p(0) = 1 and p(42) = 3655 :-) Am I still overlooking something?

Comment: @VPfB Sorry about that, I was a bit in a hurry and forgot to comment (I even upvoted your comment!). To me, it's not a good answer to this question, because it does not use `lambda` functions, while the title mentions them (as well as the question itself), and OP even tagged `lambda`. I would not say however that this is a bad solution; I would tend to prefer simple functions over complicated lambda expressions. However, your post puts this as if it was an answer to the question, although it is not (IMO). Add some text explaining you propose an other approach, and I'll upvote ;)

Comment: @Tesla this is actually one of the two idiomatic solutions (the other one being using a custom callable)

Comment: @Rightleg the fact the OP mentionned lambdas doesn't mean the pythonic solution would be to use a lambda.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers Although I agree with you, no mention to pythonicity was made

Comment: @Rightleg this doesn't mean we shouldn't care about pythonicity - part of the point of SO is to promote good practices, isn't it ?

Comment: Sorry I was mistaking. Still have the problem that I get an error just like I do on the other suggested codes. Need to figure out why.

Comment: @Tesla if you're using Python3 you have to replace `print whatever` statements with `print(whatever)` function calls.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers I couldn't agree more.

Comment: You could simplify the evaluation a bit by consuming the coefficients in the original order and using Horner's rule: `for c in coefs: result = result * x + c`.

Comment: That was not the issue, but I figured it out now, too embarrassing to point out.

Answer (score 4):

The most obvious pythonic solution (using a closure - with a lambda or (preferably) a named inner function) has already been posted, but for the sake of completeness I'll add the other pythonic solution - the OO version using a custom callable class:

```
class Polynomial(object):
    def __init__(self, coef):
        self.coef = coef

    def __call__(self, x):
        n = len(self.coef) - 1
        return sum(c * x ** (n - i) for (i, c) in enumerate(self.coef))

p = Polynomial([2,3,1])
print p(0)
print p(42)
```

Comment: +1 for the completeness. Besides, this solution is scalable, in the sense that more complex behaviour can be added later, while closures are alright because the case is pretty simple.

Answer (score 1):

The following lambda function evaluates a polynomial function, input as a `coeff` list of coefficients, in a given x:

```
from functools import reduce

lambda coeff, x: reduce(lambda a, b: a*x + b, coeff)
```

It seems that you want to generate these polynomial functions. You can still do it with this method:

```
def generate_polynomial(coeff):
    return lambda x: (lambda y: reduce(lambda a, b: a*y + b, coeff))(x)

>>> p = generate_polynomial([20,0,17])
>>> p(10)
2017
```

This is merely based on [Horner's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horner%27s_method).

Besides, if you want to use exclusively `lambda` and no built-in functions, you can also emulate `reduce` with `lambda` functions. You might want to give a look at [Python - Removing duplicates in list only by using filter and lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41522601/python-removing-duplicates-in-list-only-by-using-filter-and-lambda) and [Removing duplicates using only lambda functions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41524133/7051394), showing how to get rid of the `filter` function.

Comment: Thank you. What does the error "<function polynomial.<locals>.<lambda> at 0x7faf9bab6378>" mean, that is what I get if trying your code.

Comment: @Tesla Could you please give more feedback? What you commented is just an address, it lacks the reason why it fails... Besides, it works perfectly on my Python 3.4, it might be a problem with Python 2?

Comment: I use Python 3.4 as well, the problem occurs on the other codes as well.. Where can I check the reason? Sorry I am not too familiar with it yet.

Comment: @Tesla Now that I read more closely what you commented, it appears that this is not an error, but just the address of the function you generated. Did you do something like `p = generate_polynomial(...)`, then `print p`? If so, `p` is a function, so you will want to evaluate it on a value to get a printable result. Try with `print(0)` for instance.

Comment: That was not the issue, I did something terrible, but I fixed it now hehe.

Comment: @Tesla I'm afraid to ask what terrible thing you did, but I'm pretty curious too...

Comment: I just put >>>generate_polynomial([20,0,17]) instead of >>>p=generate_polynomial([20,0,17]).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132907/discussion-between-right-leg-and-tesla).

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using lambda:

```
def polynomial(coef):
  n = len(coef) - 1
  return lambda x : sum([c * x ** (n - i) for (i, c) in enumerate(coef)])
```

Lambda isn't necessary however, you can define another function inside the polynomial function like so:

```
def polynomial(coef):
  def f(x):
    n = len(coef) - 1
    return sum([c * x ** (n - i) for (i, c) in enumerate(coef)])
  return f
```

Edit: Previously input was tied to 3 coefficients

Comment: The input is a list of arbitrary length though. Also, the list is the only input of the main function.