# Deleting duplicate customers in Stripe API

Tags: python, list, rest

I am trying to write code that will compare customers and remove duplicate ones.

how do i compare params of each customer to the rest in filtered_customers and add it to a list?

```
import stripe

stripe.api_key = "sk_test_51OQA44ESuCeG...hZce"

customers = stripe.Customer.list(limit=100) 
filtered_customers = [] 

for customer in customers: 
  
  if customer["id"] is not None:
    filtered_customers.append(customer)
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow community. Why not just filter `customers` list first before you iterate over it? Check this lamba expression for filtering: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41524033/2976876

Comment: @smithnblack hmm.. isn't that the same as:
for customer in customers: 
  
  if customer["id"] is not None:
    filtered_customers.append(customer)


sorry, i am new to this

Answer (score 0):

> There is a few ways to do this but there are some considerations. If there is a duplicate profile of a customer how would you choose which to keep? You would probably want the most recent one. Checking  [customer API object][1]the customer dict object "created" is a unix timestamp which you can use to filter

````
customers = [
  #your customers

]

# Dictionary to hold the most recent customer for each unique identifier
unique_customers = {}

for customer in customers:
    try:
        #identifier can be 'email' or another field like 'id' if no 'email'
        identifier = customer.get("email") or customer.get("id")

        
        #added error handling in case identifier is null or not the right type
        if identifier is None:
            raise ValueError("Identifier (email or id) is missing")
        if not isinstance(customer.get("created"), (int, float)):
            raise ValueError("Invalid or missing 'created' timestamp")

       # Compare 'created' timestamps and keep the most recent customer
       #if unique_customers[identifier]["created"] is unclear remember we 
       #made a new dict where email/id is the key as identifier
        if identifier not in unique_customers or customer["created"] > unique_customers[identifier]["created"]:
            unique_customers[identifier] = customer

    except KeyError as e:
        print(f"Missing key in customer data: {e}")
    except ValueError as e:
        print(f"Data error with customer : {e}")

# Extract the filtered customers
filtered_customers = list(unique_customers.values())
print(filtered_customers)
    ```


  [1]: https://stripe.com/docs/api/customers/object?lang=python
````